# What is the memory-style game that has pawn-like tokens covering pictures?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember a while ago having played a memory-like game which had blue plastic "pawns" which covered holes in a round cardboard sheet, while a second lower layer of cardboard was able to rotate underneath.  There were pictures on the lower layer which corresponded to the holes in the upper layer, and there were several different possible picture combinations.  What is that game called?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What sort of pictures were they? Do you remember any of the rules?

Comment: I remember the holes were about 1/2" in diameter, and there must have been twenty or thirty.  The rules were pretty much the same as the rules of Memory (each player in turn takes up two "pawns", and if the pictures underneath are identical, the player keeps the pawns and continues; when the pictures that are uncovered are not identical, the player replaces the pawns, and the next player takes a turn.)  I can't remember what the pictures were exactly, but they were idealized and simple depictions of things like rabbits, birthday cakes, etc.

Comment: P.S. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)) calls it *Concentration* instead of *Memory*.

Comment: Hmm. I know this game as Pairs, and we play it with a standard deck of cards, but there are [hundreds of implementations](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7688/memory) of this mechanic out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after asking a few people, I've found the game: [Hūsker Dū?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C5%ABsker_D%C5%AB%3F):

[image: Hūsker Dū?]

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the band Husker Du were named after a boardgame.  I wonder if they're the only ones!